# Parsing An ArrayList of BufferedImages From FFmpeg

Tags: java, arraylist, ffmpeg, frames

I am using FFmpeg in my java app to turn a video into an ArayList of BufferedImages. Im am using this code to split a video file into individual jpg frames:

```
builder.command(FFmpeg, "-i", "<video url>", "-vf", "fps=5,scale=128:128,format=rgb8,format=rgb24", "out%d.jpg");
```

This produces a folder full of jpg frames, it works fine. But I would rather not write them to individual files, I would rather make that output turned into an ArrayList of BufferedImages, WITHOUT having to write each frame to a seperate file.

*This should be what the command line would look like for the above code:*

```
FFmpeg.exe -i <video url> -vf fps=5,scale=128:128,format=rgb8,format=rgb24 out%d.jpg
```

If its not possible to parse the ArrayList directly, what other solutions do I have which would be more elegant?

Comment: Are you forced to use ffmpeg? There are other libraries available to do such stuff.

Comment: @chris No not really. I would like something that can read a file from a url like www.mysite.com/content/video.avi. And something which could pass the same sort of parameters as the ones im using.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to give [openimaj](http://www.openimaj.org/) a try.
  You can load videofiles and extract the images from there. The used format can be tranformed to a java buffered image. Here is an example: http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial/processing-video.html.